# "drop" comments/issues

Tags: expressions

The situation is that I review contracts and exchange comments back and forth with counter-parties. When they reject my comments and if I don't want to pursue my position, I would write, "I will drop this issue/comment/request."

Is this a natural way to express the above position? 
What other expressions could there be, if any, in negotiation?

Answer (score 1):

It is quite natural to say that you will “drop the issue” but it would not be so natural to say you will drop a comment or request. A request could be retracted, and you could allow the other party to disregard a comment.

In summary, natural and well-accepted negotiating terms mean you could:

- concede a point;
- retract a request;
- allow a comment to be disregarded;
- drop an issue.